# googlequicksearchbox error

Tags: android, inputstream, android-logcat, microphone

I am creating an app that access google map api to give location based services. I have nothing to do with the microphone still I am getting the following error in the logcat. As suggested by some websites I have already disabled my microphone and google app.I am a new user to android please,help.

ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=10030 pid=-1

```
[ 03-23 05:42:02.309  1574: 6149 E/         ]
```

Request requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

> 03-23 05:42:02.309 1574-6149/? E/AudioFlinger: openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
>   03-23 05:42:02.309 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
>   03-23 05:42:02.313 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
>   03-23 05:42:02.313 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>   03-23 05:42:02.313 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@844b56e
>   03-23 05:42:02.316 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
>   03-23 05:42:02.320 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@844b56e
>   03-23 05:42:02.322 6661-6733/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
>   03-23 05:42:02.322 6661-6733/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
>   03-23 05:42:02.323 6661-6732/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
>   03-23 05:42:02.323 6661-6733/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
>                                                                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6) 
>   03-23 05:42:02.324 6661-6733/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
>   03-23 05:42:02.337 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
>   03-23 05:42:02.337 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
>   03-23 05:42:02.337 6661-6735/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
>   03-23 05:42:02.337 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
>   03-23 05:42:07.345 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
>   03-23 05:42:07.345 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
>   03-23 05:42:07.346 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
>   03-23 05:42:07.349 6661-6661/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
>   03-23 05:42:07.353 6661-6733/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
>   03-23 05:42:07.355 6661-7408/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@be90ea0
>   03-23 05:42:07.358 1574-7906/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xb0797180 tid=7906 ready to run